# Getting a printf statement to work in openCL Kernel code

Tags: c, string, escaping, kernel, opencl

In the following snippet I'm trying to use `printf()` in the code to try and print out the result of the `input[i]` calculation so I can see that it's working correctly.

This isn't working as I had hoped however because the quotation marks in `printf()` mess with the string format for the kernel such that the entire program won't compile. I've tried using the escape character `\"` which does allow me to type the string for the kernel but when compiled gives me expected expression and missing character errors.

Does anyone know how to solve this? And is this the best way to check kernel code results?

```
    const char *KernelSource =         "\n"
"__kernel void relax(                    \n"
"   __global double* input,                \n"
"   __global double* output,               \n"
"   __global int N)             \n"
"{                                        \n"
"   int i = get_global_id(0);             \n"
"   if(i > 0 && i < N-1){                         \n"
"       input[i] = 0.25*input[i-1]+0.5*input[i]+0.25*input[i+1];  \n"
"       printf("input[%d] %f \n", i, input[i] )\n"
"   }                                        \n"
"}                                        \n"
"\n";
```

Comment: Could you provide some more detail? Why are you building this function into a string? When you escape the string what error do you get?

Comment: Are you doing this on an OpenCL platform that supports in kernel printf? It isn't part of the standard and not all vendors support it.

Comment: Yeah I've just used nos' answer for escaping \n and now it's not working because it doesn't recognise printf. I have no idea how to print the output without printf now.

Comment: What device are you using?  If you are using a CPU, this is possible, but if you are using a GPU, then this is not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes and you need to escape the `\` for the `\n` inside the format string.

```
"       printf(\"input[%d] %f \\n\", i, input[i] )\n"
```

Comment: No, like I've said, I tried that. I'm getting the error messages that I said above.

Comment: @Chucky If you're getting an error message from some where, please copy/paste that error message and show us, and tell us which tool is generating it.

Comment: I'm not sure whether to accept your answer yet as I've still not been able to recognise printf() in the kernel code. Your suggestions got it to recognise in the first place though!

Comment: @Chucky The OpenCL tutorial, http://opencl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=OpenCL%20Tutorials%20-%201 shows how to communicate results. It's non-trivial, you have to pass back data to your application and have the application e.g. print it. You're likely much better off specifying the opencl code in separate files though, not as strings in your host C program.